# How can I change textAlignment of all UILabels in all storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, storyboard, uilabel

How can I set the `textAlignment` property on all UILabels in all storyboards to `NSTextAlignmentNatural`?

Our app has many storyboards and xib files, with many screens and UILabels.  In order to localize for RTL languages (Hebrew, Arabic) the `textAlignment` properties need to be `NSTextAlignmentNatural` instead of Left alignment.

Xcode 6.3.2 storyboard editing only supports setting left, center, or right alignment, so that's not an option.  It has to be done in code somewhere.  One solution is to traverse the view hierarchy in `viewDidLoad` and fix all `UILabels`, but there are a lot of view controllers.  Is there any way to override or supplement `viewDidLoad` in one place that would apply to all view controllers?  Method swizzling is not an option we want to use.  Is there any other way?

The only solution I can see (other than swizzling or modifying all `viewDidLoad` methods) is to subclass `UIViewController`, add the code to `viewDidLoad`, then change all VC's to be a subclass of that.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can create custom Label by sub classing UILabel and add code it to  NSTextAlignmentNatural and set that in every storyboard and xib..!

Answer (score 2):

A solution came up to my mind, I'm not totally sure that it could work, but I'd like to share with you.
You can subclass `UILabel` and create a new property that conforms to `UIAppereance` protocol, this property would set the text alignment.
Maybe a category would be enough.
Using Appereance proxy you can can make a customization application wide, of course you will need to change `UILabel` to the new custom class, but if there are no label created programmatically you can do a "find and replace" using a simple text editor on the storyboard xib.
Check [here](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-8-using-uiappearance-for-a-custom-look/) and [here](http://petersteinberger.com/blog/2013/uiappearance-for-custom-views/) to see how to conform method to the appereance proxy.

Comment: I wanted to avoid replacing `UILabel` in every storyboard with a custom subclass, but doing that with a global search and replace does sound like a option.